# How to query all instances of a nested field with variable paths in a MongoDb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that has documents with a field called `overridden`. I need to find the number of times `overridden: true`.

So for example, I have a collection as follows:

```
[ // assume this is my collection / array of documents

    { // this is a document
        textfield1: {
            overridden: true,
        },
        page1: {
            textfield2: {
                overridden: true,
            },
            textfield3: {
                overridden: false,
            }
        },
        page2: {
            section1: {
                textfield4: {
                    overridden: true,
                }
            }
        }
    },

    { // this is a different document
        page1: {
             section1: {
                 textfield1: {
                     overridden: false,
                 },
                 textfield2: {
                     overridden: false,
                 }
             },
             section2: {
                 textfield3: {
                     overridden: true,
                 }
             }
       }
    }
}
```

So from the above, I need to get `# of fields overridden = 4`.

This is a simplified example of how the documents in the collection are structured. I'm attempting to show that:

1. There is no guaranteed structure to find the path to each `overridden` field in the document.
2. I need to aggregate across documents in the collection.

From research online, I did the following:

```
db.reports.aggregate()
    .group({
        _id: "overridden",
        totalOverridden: { 
            "$sum": { 
                $cond: [ { "overridden": true }, 1, 0]
            }
        }
    })
```

That gave me a value of 2472 in the actual collection, which looks like the total number of times that field occurs because if I remove the entire `$cond` I still get the same value. From the looks of it, `{ "overridden": true }` always returns true, because if I flip the if-else return values (or just do `$sum: 1`), I get 0.

If it's any help, I do actually have mongoose schemas with defined paths for each `overridden` field but the schema is a bit large and heavily nested, therefore tracking each path would be quite tedious. That being said, if the above is not possible, I'm open to suggestions for analyzing the schema/document JSON as well to get the different paths and somehow using those to query all the fields.

Thanks a ton! I'd appreciate any help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but not very pretty.  You can repeatedly convert the object to any array, eliminate all fields that do not contain objects or have the name "overridden", and repeat.

There is no flow control in an aggregation pipeline, so you won't be able to have it automatically detect when to stop.  Instead, you'll need to repeat the extraction for the number of levels of embedding that you want to support.

Perhaps something like:

```
reapeating = [
  {$unwind: {
      path: "$root",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,

  }},
  {$unwind: {
      path: "$v",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
  }},
  {$match: {
      $or: [
        {"root.k": "overridden", "root.v":true},
        {"root.v": {$type: 3}}
      ]
  }},
  {$project: {
      root: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "object",
              {$type: "$root.v"}
            ]
          },
          then: {$objectToArray: "$root.v"},
          else: "$root"
        }
      }
  }}
]
```

Then to find all "overridden" fields down to 5 levels deep:

```
pipeline = [
      {$project: {
         _id: 0,
         root: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"}
      }}
];
final = [
  {$match: {
      "root.k": "overridden",
      "root.v": true
  }},
  {$count: "overridden"}
];
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  pipeline = pipeline.concat(repeating)
}
pipeline = pipeline.concat(final);
db.reports.aggregate(pipeline)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RM3Cu2e5pnL)

Comment: Brilliant- I truly appreciate it. I do want to understand this a bit better though, for my own clarity. Why did you choose to set `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true`? The way I understand it is that the unwind step would convert null objects to empty arrays- is there any reason why we would want to keep those around?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on the $unwind rules, I notice that when the field being unwound does not contain an array, it is not passed on at all unless you specify preserverNullAndEmptyArrays.  For example `{v:true}` may be lost with `{$unwind: "$v"}`

Comment: So `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true` helps to preserve documents(retain docs) where field which is being unwind i.e; `v` equals to `null` or `[]`(empty array) or not present at all. If you just use `{$unwind: "$v"}` it would remove all docs where `v` has these values..

Comment: That's not how I read it in the docs, but that seems to be the behavior when I run aggregations.

Comment: Just looked at their docs :: `Optional.

If true, if the path is null, missing, or an empty array, $unwind outputs the document.
If false, if path is null, missing, or an empty array, $unwind does not output a document.
The default value is false.`
Seems to be correct..